# How to use arr.includes() with object

Tags: javascript

I have array that contains object like this:

```
products: [{
 title: 'this is title',
 id: 1
 },
 title: 'this is another product',
 id: 2
}]
```

I want to check if products include `id: 1`.

Here is my try:

```
arr.includes(products[id, product.id])
```

but it's not working.

Comment: Firstly did you check what `products[id, product.id]` is? Secondly, includes with an object is likely not to work because they have to be _the exact same object instance_ to match, not just have the same props.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. ***>>>[Do some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+includes+object+array+site:stackoverflow.com)<<<***, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate the array and check the property.

```js
const
    includes = (array, key, value) => array.some(o => o[key] === value),
    products = [{ title: 'this is title', id: 1 }, { title: 'this is another product', id: 2 }];
    
console.log(includes(products, 'id', 1));
```